# Enumerate every solution for each WebApplication

Tags: 2010, solution-package, web-application, stsadm, application-pool

I'm performing an inventory and I need to get list of sharepoint solutions (*.wsp) deployed to every individual web-application and ideally, it would also be great to list what Application pool on what web-server this web-application belongs to?

Something like this >>

```
solution-name.wsp / web-application-name / application-pool-name
```

I've tried using **Get-SPSolution**, but output doesn't contain web-app name  & **Get-SPWebApplication** doesn't give the list of .wsp for each web-app listed.

**stsadm -o enumsolutions** seems to contain info I need, but don't know how to change output format to something similar mentioned above.

This is MS SharePoint Server 2010 running on W2K8R2 STD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get all your web applications and iterate through them. While in the loop print web application name and application pool name. Last, iterate all solutions and print their names - like this:

```
$contentWebAppServices = (Get-SPFarm).services |
 ? {$_.typename -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"}

foreach($webApp in $contentWebAppServices.WebApplications)
{
    Write-Host "Web Application  : " $webApp.name
    Write-Host "Application Pool : " $webApp.ApplicationPool.Name

    Get-SPSolution | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.LastOperationDetails.IndexOf($webApp.url) -gt 0) 
        {
            Write-Host "    Solutions:"
            Write-Host "   " $_.DisplayName
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Web Application  :  SharePoint - 1337
Application Pool :  SharePoint - 1337
Web Application  :  SharePoint - 80
Application Pool :  SharePoint - 80
    Solutions:
    customer.intranet.wsp
```

The first web application (SharePoint - 1337) doesn't have deployed solutions, but the second (SharePoint - 80) has one.

Comment: Perfect, I think this is what I need.